# Camel: How to skip multiple header lines in CSV files

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

I'm going to process CSV files using Apache Camel. My files have multiple header lines. In Camel I only find **skipFirstLine** or **skipHeaderRecord** (which is not clear for me) but how to skip more than one line?

Comment: I don't think this is possible out-of-the-box : as you saw skipFirstLine only skips one single line, and skipHeaderRecord seems to be there to skip extra fields on each record. I don't know Apache Camel enough to post an answer, but I suggest you find a way to trim your header before feeding the CSV to bindy

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tokenize` method on your body before processing the body.

```
tokenize(String token, int group, boolean skipFirst)
```

Example:

```
`from("filePath").
    split(body().tokenize("\n",1,true)).
    streaming().
    process(exchange -> {....}).
to("filePath");`
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of lines to skip is fixed, then you can use the simple language to skip X number. You likely need to covert the message to a String first,

```
  .convertBodyTo(String.class)
  .transform(simple("${skip(3)}")
```

See more about skip method at: http://camel.apache.org/simple

This requires Camel 2.19 onwards.

Using older releases you would need to build some custom code yourself to skip the lines.

Comment: 2.19? I think latest release is 2.18.3

Comment: It's even more complicated - I don't have to skip the first n lines but process them as well but they have different format than the rest of the lines. How to do this?

Comment: Then process them in two steps, the first where you write some code to read and process the headers, then transform the message to only the body lines which you can process using Camel CVS

Comment: Yes but how to do this? Where can I find an example?