# Camel: Skipping multiple header lines in Fixed Length File returns iterator object reference

Tags: java, apache-camel

To Preface this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520162/camel-how-to-skip-multiple-header-lines-in-csv-files) is exactly what i'm looking for. The only difference is i'm using a fixed Length file.

My problem is using this method I seem to get a Iterator Object returned and not the file with the 3 lined header removed.

The Camel route should consume a .txt file, remove the first 3 lines and then send the result to a file endpoint.

I have tried different variations of the simple language to no avail. I can't find any specific case in the book, documentation or online.

See my Camel Route Below

```
    from(inputFilePath).routeId("MyRoute")
            .streamCaching()
            .threads(threadPoolSize)
            .log("${headers.CamelFileName}: Unmarshalling to Java POJO")
            .log("${body} Body Before Transform")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .transform().simple("skip(3)")
            .log("${body} Body After Transform")
            .to(outputFilePath)
```

Im Expecting for a .txt file to be returned with the first 3 lines removed and the rest of the structure to not be changed.

Instead I get a reference to a iterator Object -->
`2019-06-19 14:55:30.497  INFO 2868 --- [ad #2 - Threads] MyRoute                            : org.apache.camel.util.SkipIterator@4d894ea5 Body After Transform`

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple function `skip(n)` is intended to skip `n` items in `List`, but your body is `String`.
You need to get `List<String>` of lines ([Tokenize language](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-base/src/main/docs/tokenize-language.adoc)) in order to use it.

To join this list back to `String` you can use eg [Bean EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/bean-eip.adoc) to call [`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

```
from(inputFilePath)
        .transform(body().tokenize("\n"))
        .transform(simple("${skip(3)}"))
        .bean(StringUtils.class, "join(${body}, '\n')")
        .to(outputFilePath);
```